# ASP core 2.0 app launched from a docker container on linux not recognizing environment variable -FIXED

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core

edit - So it turns out I there was a hidden override yaml file that was setting the variable back to development. I didn't realize it was there till I got to work and by happenstance my visual studio is set to show all files on that but for some reason wasn't on my home box. I've never been so frustrated and relieved at the same time.

I currently have a test app I am running in a docker container on linux.
Despite setting the environment variable in the compose file to Production,
it is running on a Development Environment.
Here is the yaml file.

version: '3'

services:
  template:
    image: template
    container_name: template
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Template/Dockerfile
    expose:
    - "80"
    restart: unless-stopped

```
environment:
- ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Production"
```

networks:
      default:
        external:
          name: redroom

When I launch this and go to the website.

I am testing with a index page that has the following code.

```
    <environment include="Staging">
        <p>Staging</p>
    </environment>
    <environment include="Production">
        <p>Production</p>
    </environment>
    <environment include="Development">
        <p>Development</p>
    </environment>
```

No matter what I do, I always see "Development".
I can change the environment variable on my windows development box and it all works as expected, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make this app run as "Production" in the docker container on linux.

Here is a pastbin of all the docker files.  https://pastebin.com/FeYqxuL1

Comment: What does the docker log file output show for the hosting environment on startup?

Comment: Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.  - This was from the logs for the docker container.

Comment: Is it possible your environment variables are being overridden?  What does the Dockerfile look like?  What configuration are you using to publish the app and build the docker image?

Comment: Also, are you actually using the `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` extension method in Program.cs or Startup.cs?

Comment: Brad,  I don't have that extension method, but I never needed it to see my windows environment variables, I can change them from Development or production and it all works as expected.

Comment: I'm trying to link all the relevant code but I"m having issues with the formatting.

Comment: Here is a pastbin with the files   https://pastebin.com/FeYqxuL1